# Cant pyarmor build multiple files

Tags: python

This is not a Pyarmor issue its related to the Pyinstaller part where it packs the encrypted files into an EXE im just using Pyarmor to make it easier

This is the command:
`pyarmor pack -e " --icon chainsaw.ico --onefile --add-binary 'C:/Python310/Lib/site-packages/tls_client/dependencies/tls-client-64.dll;tls_client/dependencies'" main.py`

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
80023 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 134, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 793, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "main-patched.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['main.py'],
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 445, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 606, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1063, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 888, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-matplotlib.py", line 15, in <module>
    assert mpl_data_dir, "Failed to determine matplotlib's data directory!"
AssertionError: Failed to determine matplotlib's data directory!
ERROR    Run command failed
```

This has always happened with anything concerning building into an exe so I was never able to do it I have tried everything google could offer me as a solution and nothing worked always the same and same erroor and im losing it at this point